# Webpack Encore - OpenLayers : why is not exported properly

Tags: symfony, webpack, gis, openlayers, webpack-encore

Im trying to use the OpenLayers library in my symfony application. Im using Webpack encore for managing my assets. I've used npm to download the OpenLayers library.

When im trying to use it inside a js file, only the first 'ol' class is available, the classes underneath it are not. In browser the *ol.layer.**Tile*** class is not recognised and throws an exception(Uncaught type error).

// map.js

```
require('../css/map.css');
const ol = require('ol');

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

//map.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{# STYLESHEETS-------------------------------------------------- #}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link href="{{ asset('build/map.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {#<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>#}

{% endblock %}

{# JAVASCRIPTS-------------------------------------------------- #}
{% block javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {#<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>#}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/map.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{# PAGE CONTENT-------------------------------------------------- #}
{% block title %}OpenLayers example{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add script tag if you are using `require`

```
`{#<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>#}`
```

You should require also Tile, View

```
var ol_Map = require('ol/map').default;
var ol_layer_Tile = require('ol/layer/tile').default;
var ol_source_OSM = require('ol/source/osm').default;
var ol_View = require('ol/view').default;

var map = new ol_Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol_layer_Tile({
            source: new ol_source_OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol_View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

See the document from OpenLayers http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/browserify.html

Comment: Thanks, Tan, you were right,  i had to explictly require the TIle class. Also i had to move my script tag `<script src="{{ asset('build/map.js') }}"></script>` to the body in the map.html.twig file. Why it was not working while it was in the javascripts block?

Comment: Glad to help you:)